# Merge Statement SQL Syntax

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, comparison, sql-merge

I am trying to compare 2 ID's from different tables and if they don't match the row that isn't in the source should be added.

But I am getting this error:

> PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "Person" when expecting one of the following: : = ( @ % ;

Code:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE merge_test AS
BEGIN
  MERGE person AS p
  USING person_test AS t 
     ON t.person_id = p.person_id 
   WHEN NOT MATCHED BY TARGET THEN
   INSERT(person_id,vorname, nachname, mobil, telefon, fax, e_mail, fgh_id)
   VALUES(t.person_id, t.vorname, t.nachname, t.mobil, t.telefon, t.fax, t.e_mail, t.fgh_id);
END;
/
```

Maybe my Syntax is wrong or i have to add an "execute immediate"?
I am pretty new to SQL and PL/SQL.

Comment: [As documented in the manual](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/MERGE.html#GUID-5692CCB7-24D9-4C0E-81A7-A22436DC968F) the syntax is `MERGE INTO target_table` - you forgo the `INTO`

Comment: thank you for the fast reply. i tried that already but if i change it it says: 
The Keyword "USING" is missing.
even so it is in the code

Comment: @BarbarosÖzhan thank you but i still got the error that "USING" is missing

Comment: @BarbarosÖzhan that got rid of the error "USING is missing! !!

i got "PL/SQL: ORA-00905: Keyword is missing" on where  "When not matched by target then" is written now..

Comment: It is "as" in "person as p" causing the "missing USING" problem. 
Remove these "as"s (how do I write plural for "as"?) from the query and you are good to go

Comment: i visited and changed the things that were different from mine..
but the "missing keyword erro"r came right after.

i am gonna edit the above code to show what i got right now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are some issues in your `MERGE` statement :

- take `t.person_id = p.person_id` into parentheses
- Oracle doesn't allow aliasing tables with `AS` keyword. Get rid of
  them
- this usage (`Using person_test as t`) is not possible, but use a
  subquery(`Using (select ... from person_test) t`)
- remove the clause `by target` from `When not matched by target then`
- A `MERGE` statement needs to be followed by an `INTO` clause
- the matching condition `t.person_id = p.person_id` after `ON`
  clause should be parenthesed

So use:

```
MERGE INTO person p
USING (SELECT person_id,
              vorname,
              nachname,
              mobil,
              telefon,
              fax,
              e_mail,
              fgh_id
         from person_test) t
ON (t.person_id = p.person_id)
WHEN NOT MATCHED 
THEN INSERT(person_id, vorname, nachname, mobil, telefon, fax, e_mail, fgh_id) 
     VALUES(t.person_id, t.vorname, t.nachname, t.mobil, t.telefon, t.fax, t.e_mail, t.fgh_id);
```